# ADO.NET DataSet - Have a UniqueConstraint for Columns from Different Tables

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, unique-constraint

I am writing a program in C# in .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008. I have a DataSet with two DataTables, A and B. In table A is DataColumn Y, and in table B is column Z, plus more columns in both tables. Both columns Y and Z are set to be Unique, AutoIncrementing columns.

I would like Y and Z to also be unique between the two of them. As in, if table A already has a row with a 3 in the Y column, and I'm creating a new row in table B and it wants to put a 3 in the Z column in that new row, it will instead skip 3 and put in a 4.

I have tried something that looks like it should work:

```
myDataSet.Tables["A"].Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { myDataSet.Tables["A"].Columns["Y"], myDataSet.Tables["B"].Columns["Z"] }));
myDataSet.Tables["B"].Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { myDataSet.Tables["A"].Columns["Y"], myDataSet.Tables["B"].Columns["Z"] }));
```

But, I get the following error on the first line if I run the application and it gets to that code:

> System.Data.InvalidConstraintException was unhandled
>   Message="Cannot create a Key from Columns that belong to different tables."
>   Source="System.Data"

The reason that I add the same UniqueConstraint to both tables is because, well, I'm not really sure where else to put it to make it be active. I would rather not combine the tables into one, as they have little to do with each other, other than columns Y and Z.

Does anyone know any way to do this? The MSDN documentation doesn't mention multiple tables, and it looks like no one else has tried this.

---

I've finished with the problem. In my program, I had already been using some foreign key checks to keep track of which table I was dealing with. I had thought it might be easier to go about it another way from now on, but I decided to keep my current techniques (expanding it a bit where needed, such as putting more detailed identity information in other components of my program), and it's turned out to work well.

What I ended up doing doesn't really solve my question I posted here. I apologize to the Googlers hoping to get an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx) specifically mentions a single DataTable:

> The UniqueConstraint object, which can
>   be assigned either to a single column
>   or to an array of columns **in a
>   DataTable** (emphasis mine)

I don't think you'll be able to get the DataTable to enforce this for you, you'll have to enforce the behavior manually.

Comment: Somehow missed that when I read that. Yeah, I may indeed do it manually. It's strange that DataSet doesn't have a way to enforce this for you, as I would have thought it'd be kind of common.

I may create a new table for the sole purpose of having an auto-incrementing column, and reflect new rows from there into whatever table I'm adding to.

Comment: @pgn674: how would you do this in a real database? It's not that common.